# Html form using table

Tags: html, forms, tabular

This is sign up page of my website's. I used a table to and each row has each unique input fields. But there are too close to another field. Look at the image:

[image]

How can I put some line break between two fields? As whole form is in table, I can't simply do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** If each "input line" is beetween `<p>` and `</p>` you can use a CSS rule

For example:

```
<div id="myForm">
...
...
<p><label for="firstname">Firstname:</label> <input type="text" id="firstname"/>* </p>
...
...
</div>
```

In the CSS you can declare:

```
#myform p{
 border-bottom: 1px solid black
}
```

the last parameter is the color or the value RGB followed by #

**2)** You can use the html command `<hr/>`

Comment: This does not apply to the situation (where a table is used) and causes far too much spacing˔

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS

Give the table you created a class in the table tag

```
<table class="myFormContainer">
```

Then in your style sheet create the class and give the table TD's some padding;

```
.myFormContainer tr td{padding: 0 3px 0 3px;}
```

This will create a 6px gap on the top and bottom of the td's - which of course contain your form input fields.

:)